# qlpreviewcontroller tap fullscreen in iOS

Tags: qlpreviewcontroller

what annoying me is a simple function but little references and posts from forums.

I need a function like that in the default photos' app in iOS.

When I'm browsing a photo, tap it, then the navigation bar and the tool bar on the bottom hides.

How to realize it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying your preview controller modally, it should automatically hide the toolbar. If you are pushing it into a nav controller, it will not hide the nav bar.